# Where can I find Alfresco 4 forms definitions?

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I am starting working with activiti workflows and I am using bitnami stack (http://bitnami.org/stack/alfresco) which comes with Alfresco Enterprise 4. I would like to know where can I find all forms and model definitions and how can I create new ones? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/01/09/1509) on content modeling and form configuration.